# Arguments given do not match what python sees

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

I have a python file called sample.py with a class definition of Sample object in. This object has various variables and the following function:

```
def ratioDivision(numerator, denominator):
```

Then, in my main function (in another file), I declare a **Sample object x**, and attempt to call this function:

```
x.co2overco = x.ratioDivision(float(x.co2), float(x.co))
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "csvReader.py", line 192, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "csvReader.py", line 79, in main
    x.co2overco = x.ratioDivision(float(x.co2), float(x.co))
TypeError: ratioDivision() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I can't see how I gave three arguments? Is there a issue with the referencing?

Comment: Assuming that's an instance method, you've forgotten the `self` parameter... however, note that you haven't actually provided a [mcve] to be certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method an instance method. It's first parameter should be `self`

```
def ratioDivision(self, numerator, denominator):
```

It sees 3 parameters, because the first parameter is the instance itself.

Comment: thanks. say then I'm passing an object of the same kind as self to the function: function(self, object), is it then still necessary to reference object.variable within the function?

Comment: "It sees 3 parameters, because the first parameter is the class itself." : wrong, the first parameter is the current *instance*.

Answer (score 1):

When an attribute lookup (ie `obj.name`) references a function that's an attribute of the class, then the attribute resolution mechanism yields a callable `method` object instead of the function. This `method` object is a wrapper around the function and instance, and when called it injects the instance as first argument, so in your case

```
x.ratioDivision(1, 2)
```

becomes

```
Sample.__dict__["ratioDivision"](x, 1, 2)
```

If `ratioDivision` doesn't need any access to the current instance nor class, you could just make it a plain function in your module (Python is not Java and doesn't require that everything lives in a class).

If you still want it to be accessible thru `Sample` instances (to support for class-based polymorphic dispatch or just for mere practical reasons - like not having to import both `Sample` and `ratioDivision` from your module), you can also make it a `staticmethod`:

```
class Sample(object):
    @staticmethod
    def ratioDivision(numerator, denominator):
        return whatever
```

This being said, given your example use case, ie:

```
x.co2overco = x.ratioDivision(float(x.co2), float(x.co))
```

you may want to add a method to your `Sample` class, something like `computeCo2overco()` :

```
class Sample(object):
    @staticmethod
    def ratioDivision(numerator, denominator):
        return whatever

    def computeCo2overco(self)
        self.co2overco = self.ratioDivision(float(self.co2), float(self.co))
```

or if `ratioDivision` is not expensive, just use a computed attribute:

```
class Sample(object):
    @staticmethod
    def ratioDivision(numerator, denominator):
        return whatever

    @property
    def co2overco(self):
        return self.ratioDivision(float(self.co2), float(self.co))
```

In which case you can just use:

```
whatever = x.co2coverco + something
```

and under the hood, it will call the `co2overco()` function.